# C: undefined reference to a variable when using extern

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I try to declare a global variable `config`:

```
//general.h

struct config_t {
    int num;
};

extern struct config_t config;  //The global variable
```

Then I define config variable in `general.c`:

```
//general.c
#include "general.h"

struct config_t config = {
    num = 5;
};
```

But, when I try to use the global variable 'config' in my main function, I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `config':
```

Main program:

```
//main.c
#include "general.h"

main() {
    config.num = 10;
}
```

Why is it?

Comment: Do you get that error during compilation or during linking?

Comment: @SergeyL. - During linking

Comment: To avoid linker errors, _always_ use _header guards_ `#ifndef MY_HEADER_H  #define MY_HEADER_H /* contents */ #endif`. You _must_ have this in every header file you ever make.

Comment: And like sergey answered (which is the pertinent point in this case), don't forget to link all your code together.

Comment: @Lundin A header guard won't help you outside a compilation unit. So "undefined reference" and "redefinition of" from `ld` are mostly unaffected by it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a linker error. You need to make sure you link your executable properly:

```
cc -c general.c
cc -c main.c
cc general.o main.o
./a.out
```

The `-c` flag instructs your compiler not to link yet. In order to link the object file containing `config` needs to be available at that moment.